# google maps api icons for places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API places service.
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
I get results and I want to show their icons.
I saw that many icons can be found in:
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/
usually (but nit always) with the place type name + '-71.png'
But in some other cases it uses a different name.
for example:
type synagogue has an icon:
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_jewish-71

How can I see the full list so i can match a type to an icon?

Answer (score 0):

The [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) contains an "icon" member:

```
icon | string | URL to an image resource that can be used to represent this Place's category.
```